# How/where can I best ask about resources for Computer Science self-study?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I feel that my computer science lexicon, and understanding of programming in general are not complete.

I wanted to ask something along the lines of

> What is the best book/site to learn about computer science as a whole?
>
> Rather than learning about specific programming languages, I want to understand concepts such as compiling, objects, functions/routines on a broader level. I suppose this could be called computer architecture?

The question is probably subjective, but I wasn't sure how/where to ask it. As a new user, I want to utilize this site best without sowing discord or foregoing proper etiquette.

Comment: That will sound blunt, but don't take it that way : don't ask it on the stack exchange network. It's not suited for that kind of questions. Maybe in a chat room? Or another site :)

Comment: I know I had a BLAST reading the dragonbook though (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) and it'll definitely help you learn compilers :)

Comment: Amazon's search and customer feedback are great, too - it might be worth entering some of the keywords you mention there.

Answer (score 8):

When you ask for the "best", what exactly do you mean? One [definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20best) of "best" says:

> of the most excellent, effective, or desirable type or quality

So, which do you want? The most excellent, the most effective, or the most desirable?

#### Most Excellent

If you want the most excellent, then you are asking for something that is extremely good or outstanding, which is just another way of saying that something is desirable or suited to a particular task.

Of course, there's no one correct way to answer such a question, as everyone has their own individual desires, and what may be suitable for one task may not necessarily be suitable for another. You specifically ask about learning, but learning is a [very individual process](http://www.learning-styles-online.com/overview/), so the exact "task" isn't clear.

#### Most Effective

If you want the most effective, then you are asking for something that is successful at producing the desired result.

Again, the exact result isn't clear, nor is the definition of "success" in this scenario. Will you be successful if you can talk intelligently about the history of computing, or about how compilers work, or how to properly secure a web service? These are all very different domains of knowledge with their own sub-domains, unique terminology and priorities.

#### Most Desirable

I like bananas. Apples are ok. I flat out hate boiled okra.

---

The temptation here might be to say, "Oh... well, I'll just define the scope a bit more so that this is answerable". But zoom in a bit more and you'll find that there's still more variety than you had imagined. By the time you've got an answerable question, you'll likely have answered the question.

That's why the [FAQ says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers...
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

These types of questions are narrowly scoped enough that they can generally be answered by someone with the proper domain expertise. We won't have to spend a lot of time drilling down multiple layers trying to help you find what you need, which is a huge waste of time and often generates a lot of heated debates and low-quality guessing.

Most often, "what's the best XYZ" questions are asked by relatively inexperienced programmers who are looking for a shortcut. We all started there, to be sure, so I have quite a bit of empathy for you. But there are no shortcuts, no universal "bests" that an anonymous community can select for your unique and individual situation. The best answer just about any community such as SO could offer you is: just start learning things, don't quit and [find a mentor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180715/191410).

Don't be like this guy:

[image]
http://www.qwantz.com/index.php?comic=1178

Answer (score -7):

It depends on the situation/status you are currently in. You can refer below of my inputs:

If you are a...

**Student:**

**(1)** Best to learn and share knowledge in hard coding with fellow classmates since professors tend to prohibit all needed information (lol)

**(2)** Self practice via testing modules readily available on the web.

**IT Professional:**

**(1)** Try to resolve/involve/participate in assigned tasks by your leads. With this, you can apply what you have gained during your scholastic years and practice resourcefulness.

Good luck!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question asked here, which is *On which of the SE sites can I ask this sort of question?*, to which the only acceptable answer is *None of them, because the question asks for opinion and discussion, and those types of questions are not a good fit for the specific Q&A format of SE.*.